# Create different entries each loop python tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, sqlite, tkinter-entry

I created a function to create entry boxes (tkinter) but I want to be able to access the data in the entry boxes after. Therefore, I can't call all the boxes the same name e.g. Entry1=Entry(Solo) - I have to have Entry1, Entry2 etc...

I thought that I might be able to store the Entry Names in an array but it doesn't work. I can't just store the data in a list because when creating the entry boxes there is no data to store yet.

[Update] I tried to store an entry box in an list but it's not supported. 
`TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment`

This is a snippet of code from my program (the code works without the lines with inputlist[i] on it):

```
    StudentsArray1 = c.fetchall()
    c.execute('SELECT Count(*) from students WHERE solo = 1;')
    x = c.fetchone()[0]
    a = 0
    rownum = 1

    inputlist = []

    for i in range(0, x):
        label1 = Label(Solo, text=StudentsArray1[a][0], font=font4, bg="white")
        label1.grid(row=rownum, column=1)
        label2 = Label(Solo, text=StudentsArray1[a][1], font=font4, bg="white")
        label2.grid(row=rownum, column=2)
        inputlist[i] = Entry(Solo)
        inputlist[i].grid(row=rownum, column=2)
        rownum = rownum + 1
        a = a + 1
```

Comment: You can store them in a list or a dict.

Comment: *"I tried ... an array"*: **This is not an array** => `inputarray = {}`  Read [how to use lists in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/python-lists-cheat-sheet). -  [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(x)`.